# how to make the code wait inside the following async/await function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to resize an image before uploading it to the server (with Firebase):

```
api.uploadPhoto = async (file = {}, field = {}) => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  const img = document.createElement('img')
  const reader = new FileReader()
  let fileToUpload

  reader.onload = function (e) {
    img.src = e.target.result
    pica.resize(img, canvas).then(result => {
      fileToUpload = pica.toBlob(result, 'image/jpeg', 90))
    })
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)

  // run the code below only when reader.onload has finished 

  return await imageUpload.toFirebase(fileToUpload, field)
}
```

The problem is that `imageUpload.toFirebase` is running before `reader.onload`. How to fix this?

Comment: You might want to look into promises. Here you can wait for a function to complete before starting the next one: https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the upload in to the callback ...

```
api.uploadPhoto = async (file = {}, field = {}, callback) => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  const reader = new FileReader();
  let fileToUpload;

  reader.onload = function (e) {
    img.src = e.target.result;
    pica.resize(img, canvas).then(result => {
      fileToUpload = pica.toBlob(result, 'image/jpeg', 90));
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    callback(await imageUpload.toFirebase(fileToUpload, field));

  }
};
```

Comment: I get `index.js?2848:123 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: callback is not a function`

Comment: did you provide a callback function ? as per the code sample (i modified your inputs slightly)